# FB understanding the action taken for a Send Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect

I'm writing an application that will offer a [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) for Facebook, which awards the user points.  I want to record if a "Send" action is taken.  So I thought the redirect_uri might be a way to do this, but there is no difference between if the user clicks Cancel or Send in the redirect.  Any suggestions on how best to identify the action taken?  I'd also like to know if they sent it to one friend or 20 friends.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Is it possible to know to which friends the user sent a message using the Facebook send dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840354/is-it-possible-to-know-to-which-friends-the-user-sent-a-message-using-the-facebo)

Comment: Steve is right. The facebook JavaScript SDK allows you do subscribe to events, as seen here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). Once the event has been fired, it will run your callback function.